# What's the best way to DRY in Angular within Django?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-templates, dry, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular, and to Django, and to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) so forgive me if this really simple and obvious... I've somehow missed it.

I have a dozen or so partials and a couple of them share a similar code block. I've learned how to use `{% include 'template.html' %}` to keep things DRY in django templates, however this doesn't work inside client side partials.

So I looked into ng-include with a `<div ng-include="/groups/template.html"></div>` and while that kind of works it changes the scope (which is over my head) so I cannot get my partials code to work on that included codeblock. But my biggest issue here is that the code block I'm including has to be via a routable URL in the `urls.py` file. This seems to go against security and usability.

Is what I'm asking for even possible? I'd love Angular to grab an external codeblock and drop it into the partials file server side when it puts the partials file into the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular templates should be placed in your static folder like js files.
The structure can be like this one:

```
static/
      js/
      views/ #Put here your angular templates
```

Then, you can call ng-include like this:

```
<div ng-include="{{ STATIC_URL }}views/template.html"></div>
```